# How to manage Playwright with two projects (node & .net) deployed on the same platform?

Tags: playwright

I am a newbie in Playwright, suppose if I have two projects one in .Net and another in Nodejs, deployed on the same platform, is there any possibility that playwright will allow me to write test cases for both of them at one shot with typescript as base language or i need to create 2 separate projects, 1 for node and another for .Net?

Since I am newbie, i need guidance, for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Playwright provides the flexibility to manage multiple [projects](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-projects) from single playwright framework.

Projects can be logically divided based on multiple factors like different applications(like in your case dot Net and Nodejs), different browsers/devices or even with different configurations.

Projects are configured in the `playwright.config.ts` file and once configured you can then run your tests on all projects or only on a specific project. You can also use projects to run the same tests in different configurations or different environments altogether.

#### Configure Projects for [multiple environments](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-projects#configure-projects-for-multiple-environments)

```
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  timeout: 60000, // Timeout is shared between all tests.
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'staging',
      use: {
        baseURL: 'staging.example.com',
      },
      retries: 2,
    },
    {
      name: 'production',
      use: {
        baseURL: 'production.example.com',
      },
      retries: 0,
    },
  ],
});
```

#### Projects to run same tests with different configurations

```
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
    },

    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Firefox'] },
    },

    {
      name: 'webkit',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Safari'] },
    },

    /* Test against mobile viewports. */
    {
      name: 'Mobile Chrome',
      use: { ...devices['Pixel 5'] },
    },
    {
      name: 'Mobile Safari',
      use: { ...devices['iPhone 12'] },
    },

    /* Test against branded browsers. */
    {
      name: 'Microsoft Edge',
      use: { 
        ...devices['Desktop Edge'], 
        channel: 'msedge' 
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'Google Chrome',
      use: { 
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'], 
        channel: 'chrome' 
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

Source: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-projects